# In this sentence, should "in" or "at" be used before "colleges", "parties", and "family reunions"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, sentence

> She talked about shoes all the time: [...] college, [...] parties, and
>   even [...] family reunions.

Which one should I use in the sentence above? (should I also include *while*?)

Comment: Who says you have to use only ***one**?* Personally, I'd be quite likely to say *"... in college, at parties, and even at family reunions."* In Google Books, *"when I'm **in** college"* is almost 10 times more common than the corresponding ***at*** version (which probably normally means *at some time in the future, when I start attending college)*.

Comment: 'in college' is frequently used, but normally means that you are enrolled as a student, not that you are currently located at the college.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*At* would be appropriate. *At* is used to indicate places or activities. *In* could be used for college ("in college") as it's valid to do something *inside* a location such as a college. It's not correct to do something *in* a party, as a party is not a location.

> She talked about shoes all the time at college, at parties and even at family reunions.